# SAP Link from one report to the other

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

I'm trying to add link in my SAP report to another report.

I'm trying to do this in web view, like it descripted in official manual. I click on the cell, then **Linking** then **Add Document Link...**

In popup window when I click **Browse...** I get the error

> NullPointerException
>
> [image]

Googling doesn't help.

SAP BO version:
Build Number: 1036
Product Version:  14.0.6
Both reports are WebI reports.

Comment: how do you link reports together?? do you have a report viewer page with IDs for each report??

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add which kind of document it is (both source and target): WebI, Crystal Reports, … as well as the version of BusinessObjects you're using. Also, adding the generated OpenDocument link would be welcome.

Comment: @Abdulrahman_88 I'm trying to do this in web view, like it descripted in official manual. I click on the cell, then Linking then Add Document Link...

I don't get the list of reports, I get NullPoiter instead

Comment: @Kristof I'm using SAP BO version 4.6SP1. Both reports are WebI reports.

Comment: @AlexanderCamperov 4.6 is a non-existent release. The most recent release is BI 4.1, with SP05. I suspect you're using the (D)HTML client for Web Intelligence? What application server are you using (Tomcat, WebSphere, …) and what is the version? As it doesn't look like a client issue but more of a back-end problem, any and all information regarding your architecture could be helpful.

Comment: @Kristof Here what I got from SAP web console:
Build Number: 1036 Product Version: 14.0.6

Comment: i think you are getting wrong report path, you need to include the complete report path in your hyperlink. i can give an example if you need.

Answer (score 0):

in your required column add this code under hyperlink as website on the internet:

```
IF NOT ISNULL({Your Column}) THEN "http://" & Cstr ({?@URL}) & "/Reports/"Your report viewer".aspx?ID=" & CStr(round("Report ID(s)",0))
```

and in your viewer code file you need to set the (@URL) Parameter:

add this property to your viewer

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property BaseSiteUrl() As String
    Get
        Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
        Dim baseUrl As String = context.Request.Url.Authority + context.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd("/"c)
        Return baseUrl
    End Get
End Property
```

and

```
 Your report object.SetParameterValue("@URL", BaseSiteUrl)
```

it`s a work around the path and clearing data.

**hope it help your problem.**